# How to build this DB table (Progress)

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge, progress-db

First off apologies for the newb question but I'm kinda new to Progress, here's what i'm trying to do: I have a db table called 'car' which has a field 'type' and the options are either automatic or manual. I'd like to use 1 smartbrowser to display the data in this form:

name | price | name | price

the first two columns are for automatic cars, the rest - for manual. Bear in mind, this table would be just for review, there won't be any operations allowed so it doesn't matter if it's not practical, they just need to be on 1 row.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  A SQL Fiddle is also very helpful.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createview.html

Comment: Guys, many thanks for the quick input but I found a way to do what I want. Basically just edited the temptable to include another set of name/price fields and assign them after another for each iteration. Cheers tho!

Comment: in that case you need to add the answer to the question,or delete the question.

Comment: progress is not postgres.  nor is it sql.

Answer (score 1):

First off, run away from smartObjects. They're no longer supported by PSC and are outdated anyway. I'd use a regular browse with a temp-table kind of like this:

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttCar
  FIELD autoName    AS CHARACTER
  FIELD autoPrice   AS DECIMAL
  FIELD manualName  AS CHARACTER
  FIELD manualPrice AS DECIMAL. 
/* Go ahead and add an index, for this example I'll skip it */
```

And then you do something like this before opening the browse:

```
FOR EACH car NO-LOCK:
    CREATE ttCar.
    IF car.type = "AUTO" THEN 
       ASSIGN ttCar.autoName  = car.name
              ttCar.autoPrice = car.price.
    ELSE /* MANUAL */
       ASSIGN ttCar.manualName  = car.name
              ttCar.manualPrice = car.price.
END. /* FOR EACH */

{&open-query-{&browse-name}}
```

Hope it helps... let me know if this is not what you're looking for or if you HAVE to use smartBrowses, in which case you'll need to add the fields as calculated fields and fill them from functions. This will probably impact performance, though. But I can probably make you one example, if you absolutely must.